Issue with AddForce to player object in Unity
I'm having a problem with AddForce to player rigidbody. The issue is I made playerMovement with changing velocity and it is constantly overwriting player velocity and then when I want to AddForce to player it is instantly overwritten. Problem is in the first if statement both of those playerRb.velocity.
private void DefaultMoveRigidBody()
{
    Vector3 move = new Vector3(movementInput.x, 0, movementInput.y);
    Vector3 MoveVector = transform.TransformDirection(move) * movementSpeed;
    slopeMovementDirection = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(MoveVector, slopeHit.normal);

    if (Physics.CheckSphere(FeetTransform.position, 1f, layerMask) && canJump && OnSlope())
    {
        playerRb.velocity = slopeMovementDirection;
    }
    else
    {
        playerRb.velocity = new Vector3(MoveVector.x, playerRb.velocity.y, MoveVector.z);
        Debug.Log(playerRb.velocity);
    }

    if (jumped && Physics.CheckSphere(FeetTransform.position, 1f, layerMask) && canJump)
    {
        canJump = false;
        jumpTimer = 0.5f;
        playerRb.velocity = new Vector3(playerRb.velocity.x, 0, playerRb.velocity.z);
        playerRb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
    
    if (!canJump)
    {
        if (jumpTimer <= 0f)
        {
            canJump = true;
            jumpTimer = 0.5f;
        }
        else
        {
            jumpTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    if (move != Vector3.zero)
    {
        Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(-move, Vector3.up);
        gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).transform.localRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).transform.localRotation, toRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}

rb.AddForce is in another file with ForceMode.Impulze.
My goal is to push player on contact.
Is there some way to calculate final velocity or should I try a different method of player movement?

mixing kinematic and dynamic things causes these problems. don't use add force. just set your vertical velocity when you want to jump.
if i understood and you have a 2d game where Y is up. then when you want to jump, just do this. don't worry, it works like adding force.
playerRb.velocity = new Vector3(playerRb.velocity.x, jumpForce, playerRb.velocity.z);

or if you have to jump using force, then move player by force too. just instead of speed, declare max speed and acceleration. then in your update check if velocity is higher than max speed and if it is, lower it.
